# Bounds of determinant of symmetric positive definite integer matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, upper-lower-bounds, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Given an invertible integer matrix $X \in \mathbb{Z}^n_+$, we set $A = X^T X + 1$ with $1$ denoting the identity matrix. Then, with the help of the Hadamard inequality, it is easy to find an upper bound on the determinant. But what is the lower bound of the determinant?

Since the matrix is positive definite (because $X$ is invertible), the matrix $A$ is invertible, hence, $\det A \neq 0$. It is integer and therefore we obtain $\det A \geq 1$. But so far I did not find a matrix $X$ such that $\det A = 1$. Does there exist a better bound on the determinant or does somebody know an example in order to verify that the bound is strict?

Comment: Does the symbol $\mathbb Z_+$ mean nonnegative integers or positive integers?

Comment: Hello, positive integers: therefore $A_{i,j}\geq 1$.

Comment: For a crude bound $\det\big(X^TX\big)=\det\big(X\big)^2 \geq 1$, so $\det\big(A\big) = \det\big(X^TX + I\big)\geq \det\big(X^TX\big) +\det\big( I\big) \geq 1+1=2$

Comment: How is the integrality of $X$ relevant? Why not work with real matrices?

Comment: I was lead to this problem by studying Gramian matrices as were discussed in my lecture. In this lecture we allways assumed that X is integral and therefore I want to use the same constraint. It is quite common to do this in optimization because computer programs can only work with rational numbers and you can transform each inequality system with rational numbers into one with only integral numbers in the input data.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $X^tX$ is positive semidefinite so all it's eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$  are nonnegative. Moreover since $X$ is invertible with integer entries we have $\det(X^tX)=1$, thus $\lambda_1\lambda_2\ldots \lambda_n=1$. We have that $\det(A)=(1+\lambda_1)(1+\lambda_2)\ldots (1+\lambda_n)$. For any nonnegative $x$ the inequality $1+x\geq 2\sqrt{x}$ holds so $\det(A)\geq 2^n$. There is no equality since this would imply $X=I_n$ and you assumed that $X$ has positive entries.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Yes, I fear there is a missunderstanding. While the matrix A is positive definite, X is a positive integer matrix, not necessarily positive definite.

Comment: @samabu No, what Vlad seems to misunderstand is not that $X$ is positive definite, but that $X$ has an integer matrix inverse. (That's why he claims that $\det(X^TX)$ is precisely equal to $1$: when both $X$ and $X^{-1}$ are integer matrices, both $\det(X)$ and $\det(X^{-1}$ are integers. It follows that $\det(X)=\pm1$ and $\det(X^TX)=1$.)

Comment: Ok, thank you for explaining.

Comment: The post says invertible integer matrix $X$

Comment: If you just mean $\det(X)\neq 0$ then you can just use $(1+\lambda_1)(1+\lambda_2)\ldots(1+\lambda_n)\geq (1+\sqrt[n]{\lambda_1\ldots\lambda_n})^n=(1+\sqrt[n]{\det(X)^2})^n$.